# How do you use CsvHelper.CsvWriter with F# option types?

Tags: f#, csvhelper

I am trying to save an F# record collection to a csv file using the .Net CsvHelper library. The problem is that option types are not being converted to string correctly.

```ml
#r "nuget: CsvHelper"

open System.IO 
open System.Globalization
open CsvHelper

type Record = { X : string; Y : float option }

let writeString x =
    use writer = new StringWriter()
    use csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    csv.WriteRecords(x)
    writer.ToString()

[{ X = "hi"; Y = Some 1.00}
 { X = "bye"; Y = None }]
|> writeString
```

I expect a blank value (or any other `nan` value that CsvProvider will understand) for the second field in the second data row here. Instead, CsvHelper is converting the `None` value to `0`.

```
val it : string = "X,Value
hi,1
bye,0
"
```

I am aware that `FSharp.Data.CsvProvider` would let me convert this simple record to a `CsvFile.Row` that can be saved. But that's a poor solution when you have many fields because it is hard to keep the order of the fields in the `CsvFile.Row` straight (imagine 50 float fields). I'd prefer a solution in which the record fields are converted automatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like there's no built-in support for F# in CsvHelper, so you probably have to write your own [type converter](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/configuration/class-maps/type-conversion) to handle options. Here's a quick one I whipped up:

```
open System.IO 
open System.Globalization
open CsvHelper
open CsvHelper.TypeConversion

type OptionConverter<'T>() =
    inherit DefaultTypeConverter()
    override __.ConvertToString(value, row, memberMapData) =
        match value :?> Option<'T> with
            | None -> ""
            | Some x -> base.ConvertToString(x, row, memberMapData)

type Record = { X : string; Y : float option }

let writeString x =
    use writer = new StringWriter()
    use csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    csv.Context.TypeConverterCache.AddConverter<Option<float>>(OptionConverter<float>())
    csv.WriteRecords(x)
    writer.ToString()

[<EntryPoint>] 
let main _ =
    [{ X = "hi"; Y = Some 1.00}
     { X = "bye"; Y = None }]
        |> writeString
        |> printfn "%s"
    0
```

Output is:

```
X,Y
hi,1
bye,
```

FWIW, there are CSV libraries that are easier to use from F#, such as the [FSharp.Data CSV provider](https://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/CsvProvider.html).

Comment: That looks really good! I think that in OptionConverter, instead of `None->null` we need `None -> ""` so that we get a "," after bye. Also, do you by any chance know how to use the [automapper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/configuration/class-maps/auto-mapping) with this so that I don't have to type out the Mapper for X?

Comment: I use CsvProvider a lot, but it doesn't have an easy type-safe way to convert a record to a CsvFile.Row. `fun (x:Record) -> CsvFile.Row(x.X,x.Y)` is easy to result in mixed up fields when you have 50 float fields.

Comment: I've updated my answer to auto-map and output the empty string for `None`.